# Find exact script from PID

Tags: linux, ssh, php, process

I'm having some trouble on my hosting with too many entry processes running. The hosting company has given me SSH access so I can monitor things more accurately, currently just using `top` or `ps aux`. I've found a process that doesn't seem to be finishing off and it's a php script `lsphp`. However there are a lot of PHP scripts running on the server and I need to figure out which one is the one that is causing the issue. Is there anyway to figure out what the actual PHP script/file that process is connected to is rather than just that the process is being run by `lsphp`?

For example `pwdx 6608` just returns `6608: /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin` which tells me that it's a PHP process but not which actual PHP script started the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ps -f -p {pid}
```

to list the full command line that started a process.

If this is not enough, you can get the list of files open by that process using:

```
lsof -p {pid}
```

The output is huge, `grep` is your friend (keep regular files, exclude PHP runtime, include path with your files, etc....). But the open files may give you a hint.

Comment: That only seems to output the same information: `UID me PID 13480 PPID 13204  C 0 STIME 08:11 TTY ?        TIME 00:00:01 CMD lsphp`

Comment: Edited answer to add lsof solution